# Finding the size of a particle in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to allow for the particle to hit all enemies based on how big it is. The particle starts big and ends very small then dies out. However it only hits the enemies if they are directly in front of the position of the particle. I also can't just calculate the time and check above and below the particles position because I am trying to find a generic enough way to do this for all sizes and durations of a particle. Any help is extremely appreciated